# How to set Visibility for a float Action menu from another Activity

Tags: java, android

I have created a float action menu contains float action buttons in an activity,
all I need I want to show the same screen in another activity but without this float action menu which is in the main activity
I tried to setVisibily(VIEW.Invisible) in the new activity it shows me a null object refrence error how can I solve this

this is the mainActivity which contains the float action menu

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton SplitCheck, HoldItem, VoidItem, ChangeNoOfCovers, Payment;
    public static FloatingActionMenu mainFM;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mainFM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.mainFAB);
        SplitCheck = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.splitCheck);
        HoldItem = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.holdItem);
        VoidItem = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.voidItem);
        ChangeNoOfCovers = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.changeNoCover);
        Payment = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.paymentID);

        mainFM.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);
...........................
.................
}
}
```

this is my second Activity

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu;

public class TakeAwayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton fabNew;
    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_away);
        fabNew = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.newOrderTa);
        final FloatingActionMenu mainFM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.mainFAB);
        final boolean showButton = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("HIDE_FAB" , false);
        mainFM.setVisibility(showButton ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

//        MenuActivity.mainFM.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        fabNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent i = new Intent(TakeAwayActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("HIDE_FAB", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please link some code.

Comment: @Anders Kink ok Sure

Comment: @Anders Kink please check my edits

Comment: Try this:   MenuActivity.mainFM.setVisibility(View.Gone);

Comment: @Anders Kink I tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use static variables for those kind of use.

In your specific case, you are trying to access `MenuActivity.mainFM` before onCreate was execute, so it'll be necessary null.

The good way is to add an extra in your startActivity Intent, then in your onCreate method of your activity, get this extra and show or not your button.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(TakeAwayActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(MenuActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_BUTTON_KEY, true);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in your activity :

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_SHOW_BUTTON_KEY = "EXTRA_SHOW_BUTTON_KEY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        final FloatingActionMenu mainFM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.mainFAB);
        final boolean showButton = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_BUTTON_KEY , false);
        mainFM.setVisibility(showButton ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot but could u show me some example for this?

Comment: I tried ur example but it show me the same erre as "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference"

Comment: I think you put the code in the wrong activity, should be in the activity where the button is present. MenuActivity I guess.

Comment: ok great! For further feature forget about static https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil

Answer (score 0):

Because of in your `MenuActivity` you have to always hide the `FloatingActionButton` Try this inside `MenuActivity` `onCreate`:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_away);
    mainFM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.mainFAB);
    mainFM.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I think there is no need for intents because it has to be always hidden